# What happens if grid-column-end is greater than the maximum columns in css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've been studying css grid system from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids). In the *line based placement* section, after playing around a bit I saw a weird behaviour. If the layout is two column, say e.g. defined as `grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;` and to one of the children I set the `grid-column-end` greater than 2, it generates empty columns with their own `grid-gap`. Here's a working example of it https://jsfiddle.net/u1paezkw/ If you inspect the `header` you'll notice straight dotted lines representing empty columns.

```css
                body {
                    width: 90%;
                    max-width: 900px;
                    margin: 2em auto;
                    font: .9em/1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                }
                
                .container {
                    display: grid;
                    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
                    grid-gap: 20px;
                }
header {
    grid-column: 1 / 13;
    grid-row: 1;
}

article {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}

aside {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

footer {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 3;
}
        
header,
footer {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(207,232,220);
  border: 2px solid rgb(79,185,227);
}
        
aside {
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids -->

<div class="container">
  <header>This is my lovely blog</header>
  <article>
    <h1>My article</h1>
    <p>Duis felis orci, pulvinar id metus ut, rutrum luctus orci. Cras porttitor imperdiet nunc, at ultricies tellus laoreet sit amet. Sed auctor cursus massa at porta. Integer ligula ipsum, tristique sit amet orci vel, viverra egestas ligula. Curabitur vehicula tellus neque, ac ornare ex malesuada et. In vitae convallis lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse ac imperdiet turpis. Aenean finibus sollicitudin eros pharetra congue. Duis ornare egestas augue ut luctus. Proin blandit quam nec lacus varius commodo et a urna. Ut id ornare felis, eget fermentum sapien.</p>

    <p>Nam vulputate diam nec tempor bibendum. Donec luctus augue eget malesuada ultrices. Phasellus turpis est, posuere sit amet dapibus ut, facilisis sed est. Nam id risus quis ante semper consectetur eget aliquam lorem. Vivamus tristique elit dolor, sed pretium metus suscipit vel. Mauris ultricies lectus sed lobortis finibus. Vivamus eu urna eget velit cursus viverra quis vestibulum sem. Aliquam tincidunt eget purus in interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <h2>Other things</h2>
    <p>Nam vulputate diam nec tempor bibendum. Donec luctus augue eget malesuada ultrices. Phasellus turpis est, posuere sit amet dapibus ut, facilisis sed est.</p>
  </aside>
  <footer>Contact me@mysite.com</footer>
</div>
```

1. Can somebody please explain this behaviour and also please give some official reference for this. How can there be more columns than specified in `grid-template-columns`?
2. For `grid-column: 1 / 3` where is the third column? Why does line end at the end of second column?

Comment: Grid template columns defines the EXPLICIT grid. Your CSS rule grid columns for the element creates columns in the IMPLICIT grid

Comment: @Paulie_D does implicit grid rules get higher priority than explicit ones? It seems counter intuitive to me.

Comment: It's really weird, I am not asking for a book recommendation, I am asking yous to back up your reply with w3c or mdn reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and to one of the children I set the grid-column-end greater than 2, it generates empty columns with their own grid-gap.

To be more accurate, it's greated than 3 and not 2. When having 2 columns you will have 3 lines (1,2,3) so you can place an element across both column by setting `grid-column: 1 / 3`

> [image]

<sup>https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#placement</sup>

Then as stated in the comment you need to understand the concept of explicit and implicit grid. To make it easy, *you* define the explicit grid and the implicit one is defined *automatically*

> The three properties `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns`, and `grid-template-areas` together define **the explicit grid of a grid container**. **The final grid may end up larger due to grid items placed outside the explicit grid**; in this case implicit tracks will be created, these implicit tracks will be sized by the `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns` properties.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#explicit-grids)</sup>

Also

> If a grid item is positioned into a row or column that is not explicitly sized by `grid-template-rows` or `grid-template-columns`, implicit grid tracks are created to hold it. This can happen either by explicitly positioning into a row or column **that is out of range**, or by the auto-placement algorithm creating additional rows or columns. The `grid-auto-columns` and `grid-auto-rows` properties specify the size of such implicitly-created tracks. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#propdef-grid-auto-columns)</sup>

If your definition of the grid isn't enough to contain all the elements then extra row/columns are created for the purpose and the final grid is called the implicit grid. This is logical since it wouldn't make sense to have grid items that doesn't belong to the grid.

In your case, using `grid-column:1/13` will create a total of 12 columns where 2 are explicitely defined and the remaining will be `auto` and of course 11 gaps.

---

You can also build a whole grid without any explicit definition and only using the implicit one.

Example:

```css
.box {
  display:grid;
  grid-gap:10px;
}

.box > * {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

/* the below will make the grid having 3 columns */
.box > *:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column:3;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

---

> does implicit grid rules get higher priority than explicit ones? It seems counter intuitive to me

It's not about priority but you can see the implicit grid as a *needed* extension to the explicit one in order to contain all the elements.

Comment: I was expecting to see at least a note of `grid-auto-columns` :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol added ;) but it's basically repeating the same using different words.

Comment: How are grid lines defined when we have `grid-gap` in columns? If I have 2 columns(non-empty) with 20px grid gap, when I inspect I see 4 lines. Is `line` just an imaginary thing going through middle of grid gap?

Comment: @user31782 grid lines doesn't really exist. A line is something between two columns and at the start/end of grid. N columns means N+1 lines and if you place an element. If you have 2 columns then you cannot find 4 lines but only 3. What you see when inspecting the code is the boundries of your columns

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think the spec doesnt define the line properly. But, if I assume starting point of every column and the ending point of last  column as line, it justify the code. when I say `grid-column: 2 / 3;` on `footer` then the footer starts after the grid-gap, i.e. starting point of 2nd column.

Comment: @user31782 the Spec define lines, read starting from here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-concepts ... Here you will need some imagination. First start by looking at your grid without gaps (all the columns will be close to each other) and imagine that you have a line that separate each columns ... then if you add gap, you will add spaces between columns but you will not create more lines. You can even see it like you make the lines thicker as said in the Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#gutters

Comment: Can you also please explain why cant we have an `L-shaped area`  in the context of _grid-template-areas_, what if I want to have two columns in first row and three columns in second row. This can be done with bootstrap easily. I am not sure if I can put it as a separate question.

Comment: @user31782 *what if I want to have two columns in first row and three columns in second row* --> you define 6 columns then you either span 3 columns or 2 columns .. You are using a grid so you need to have the same columns in all the rows. Bootstrap is following the same logic, you have a 12-columns system and you take up as much as you want to create the layout you want

Comment: @user31782 don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue

Comment: All good mate, I was just pissed off for my question getting closed.